What is the Spirit/Breath in Ezekiel 37:9-10 the spirit in the Trichotomist theory?
Ezekiel 37:9-10.

Then he said to me, “Prophesy to the breath; prophesy, son of man, and
say to the breath, Thus says the Lord God: Come from the four winds, O
breath, and breathe on these slain, that they may live.” 10 So I
prophesied as he commanded me, and the breath came into them, and they
lived and stood on their feet, an exceedingly great army.ESV

The choice of translators in English is to take "breath" instead of "spirit." Regardless of this, what is supposed to mean. Breath would be the spirit of the trichotomists? Clearly the concept of Soul seems to be absent in this text. How was this interpreted throughout history?

1 Thessalonians 5:23 'the spirit and the soul and the body'. Hebrews 4:12 'soul and spirit'.

The Trichotomist theory is the belief that human nature consists of three parts; body, soul, and spirit. The link below gives an article called “Reformed Basics on Dichotomy and Trichotomy” by R. Scott Clark (14 March 2014). He says a good way to grasp how Reformed theology speaks about this issue is to consult the work of Louis Berkhof (1873-1957). But just going through the post by R. Scott Clark, I could not see any reference to the Ezekiel 37 text in this question. Very many scriptures are covered in the article, but not that one.
Given that the O.P. is prepared to disregard the matter of how English translators render the Hebrew of the text (re. breath, or spirit) I will go along with that because some early ideas are linked to ancient Greece, with its philosophies, and they used Greek language to express those. The question is about what the older Ezekiel text means, written in ancient Hebrew. The Bible account of Ezekiel had nothing to do with later Greek language or philosophy. The answer to what is meant by Ezekiel 37:9-10 can only be obtained by examining his text. But it certainly is not necessary, for the purpose of answering the question, to delve into how the concept of trichotomy has been interpreted throughout history.
The understanding of the text depends on grasping how this is a prophecy, Ezekiel having written down a vision God gave him, by the power of the Holy Spirit (Ezek. 37:1). There is nothing literal about the wording in this vision. It deals with spiritual concepts, albeit they do have an outworking on actual people. The vision is meant to powerfully convey God’s supernatural dealings with the then spiritually dead nation of Israel. That is what the vision graphically conveys – a valley full of dry (lifeless) bones. His people were supposed to be living witnesses for God, who had miraculously brought them out of bondage to ancient Egypt (Isaiah 43:10, 12 & 44:8) but they failed so badly, God had them taken into captivity to the world power of Babylon. Yet a time would come when God would miraculously restore them, in such a way that the nations would be astonished, as would be the Israelites themselves.
This is where going back to the prophet Isaiah’s prophecy in chapter 43 helps to explains. God addresses his exiled people to say he will miraculously bring them back, even though they had not sought him as they should, even though they had burdened and wearied God with their sins. Then, in chapter 44 come words akin to Ezekiel and the valley of dry bones:

“For I will pour water on the thirsty land, and streams on the dry
ground. I will pour my Spirit on your offspring, and my blessing on
your descendants. They will spring up like grass in a meadow, like
poplar trees by flowing streams.” Isaiah 44:1-4 N.I.V. 1987

This is a less startling illustration than Ezekiel’s vision of the valley of dry bones, but the point is the same. Only by God’s Spirit miraculously acting on nations can such new, spiritual life and liberation arise. Ezekiel is God’s mouthpiece here, telling the dry bones (which are “the whole house of Israel” vs. 11) to arise. God puts tendons and flesh on them, causing them to become human in form. Then, from the symbolic “four corners of the earth” breath is breathed into the still lifeless ones so that they stand on their feet and begin to live.
The interpretation is given by God from verse 11 to 14, which shows that there’s nothing physical about this breath, or spirit. It is spiritual spirit, from him:

“…the whole house of Israel… say, ‘Our bones are dried up and our hope
is gone; we are cut off.’ Therefore prophesy and say to them, ‘This is
what the Sovereign Lord says: O my people, I am going to open your
graves and bring you up from them; I will bring you back to the land
of Israel. Then you, my people, will know that I am the Lord when I
open your graves and bring you up from them. I will put my Spirit in
you and you will live, and I will settle you in your own land. Then
you will know that I the Lord have spoken, and I have done it,
declares the Lord’.” Ezekiel 37:11-14 N.I.V. 1987

This does not speak of Israelites who have died while in captivity in Babylon miraculously arising from their graves to go back to Israel. This is not to be taken literally. It's about spiritual deadness and renewed spiritual life. Could it be any clearer than that stated by God himself? He foretells what he will do, he does it at his appointed time, and his revitalized nation return to their land, weeping with joy. All done by the power of God’s Holy Spirit. This has got nothing to do with any trichotomy theory.
https://heidelblog.net/2014/03/reformed-basics-on-dichotomy-and-trichotomy/

At Ezekiel 37:1-10 the symbolic vision of the valley of dry bones is presented, the bones coming together, becoming covered with sinews, flesh, and skin, but “as regards breath [weruʹach], there was none in them.”
Ezekiel was told to prophesy to “the wind [ha·ruʹach],” saying, “From the four winds [form of ruʹach] come in, O wind, and blow upon these killed people, that they may come to life.”
The reference to the four winds shows that wind is the appropriate rendering for ruʹach in this case.
However, when such “wind,” which is simply air in motion, entered the nostrils of the dead persons of the vision, it became “breath,” which is also air in motion.
Thus, the rendering of ruʹach as “breath” at this point of the account (vs 10) is also more appropriate than “spirit” or “life-force.”
Ezekiel also would be able to see the bodies begin to breathe, even though he could not see the life-force, or spirit, energizing their bodies.
As verses 11-14 show, this vision was symbolic of a spiritual (not physical) revivification of the people of Israel who were for a time in a spiritually dead state due to their Babylonian exile.
Since they were already physically alive and breathing, it is logical to render ruʹach as “spirit” in verse 14, where God states that he will put ‘his spirit’ in his people so that they would become alive, spiritually speaking.
